# htaccess rewrite with conditions

Tags: .htaccess

With my htaccess file, what I want to achieve is this:

- All requests that are not for subdirectories starting with underscore or named admin should be redirected to index.php
- All requests that are a subdirectory of admin and not starting with an underscore should be redirected to admin/index.php

Examples:
http://www.example.com/controller/method -> http://www.example.com/index.php
http://www.example.com/_css/style.css -> No redirect
http://www.example.com/admin/ -> No redirect
http://www.example.com/admin/controller/method -> http://www.example.com/admin/index.php
http://www.example.com/admin/_js/script.js -> No redirect

I've got it to partially work sometimes but it wasn't pretty.

I don't think that this is hard but I haven't been able to rework any of the examples listed on the web to work with this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well that was not so hard, but please check it

whats with the trailing slash? do you have it or is it always deleted?

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^_].*)[^/]$ admin/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^_][^admin].*)/([^_].*)$  index.php[L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yes it might be trailing slashes. This works as it did when I had the best try myself even if this looks much better. However when the browser decides that it wants to add a trailing space it breaks the underscore-dirs are not working anymore

Comment: well then easily add the rule in the htacces file so the trailing lash is deleted, do you want to add a traling slash or delete it?. which code works better, well think its mine as i get some weird results with the other code from anubhava

Comment: I'm not sure what I want. If you read http://sebastians-pamphlets.com/thou-must-not-steal-the-trailing-slash-from-my-urls/ he argues that you should force the trailing slash. Rather the opposite. I honestly feel quite lost. How comes that www.site.com/admin/.+/$ is not accepted, but www.site.com/.+/$ is?

Comment: well then use the trailing slash and this should work: 
RewriteRule ^admin/([^_].*)/$ admin/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^_][^admin].*)/([^_].*)/$  index.php[L,QSA]

Comment: I used your code and finally came up with the following rules that works. RewriteRule ^admin.*/(_.+)$  admin/$1 [L,QSA], RewriteRule ^admin  admin/index.php [L,QSA], RewriteRule ^[^_].  index.php [L,QSA]. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think following rules should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*(_|admin/?) [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*admin/($|index\.php|_) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(admin/.+)$ admin/index.php?p=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works as it did when I had the best try myself even if this looks much better. However when the browser decides that it wants to add a trailing space it breaks the underscore-dirs are not working anymore